# Where to put this code in laravel?

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a table in my database which has 3 columns of type date, stored in the Y-m-d format. I need the dates to displayed in my views as d/m/Y. The model for this table is JobCard.php, so every time I retrieve an instance of JobCard I do this:

```
$JobCard -> DateReqLatest = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $JobCard -> DateReqLatest)->format('d/m/Y');
$JobCard -> DateIssued = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $JobCard -> DateIssued)->format('d/m/Y');
$JobCard -> DateDespatch = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $JobCard -> DateDespatch)->format('d/m/Y');
```

I then pass $JobCard to my view. This works but there are several views making use of this model and these views use different controllers so rather than copying this code into every controller function, I want the date format to be automatically converted when I pass an instance of JobCard to a view.

The user will also submit dates in a form in the d/m/Y format which I need to covert into Y-m-d to be stored in my database.

Where is best to write my code to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an acessor which will be called every time you access this property:

```
public function getDateReqLatestAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Laravel accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), it may be what you want if I understood.